# Time complexity of shell sort

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity, shellsort

In my textbook `Algorithms`, I read that :

> No mathematical results are available about the average-case number of
>   compares for shellsort for randomly ordered input. Increment sequences
>   have been devised that drive the asymptotic growth of the worst-case
>   number of compares down to N 4/3, N 5/4, N 6/5, . . . , but many of
>   these results are primarily of academic interest because these
>   functions are hard to distinguish from one another (and from a
>   constant factor of N ) for practical values of N.

And, here in [bigocheatsheet.com](http://bigocheatsheet.com/), it is given that the Time complexity of Shell sort as :

- Worst case : `O((nlog(n))^2)`
- Average    : `O((nlog(n))^2)`
- Best case :  `O(n)`

And, here is my implementation of shell sort:

```
/**
 * Java program to implement shell sort
 */
public class Solution
{
    private static final int arr[] = {2,5,4,3,7,8,9,1,6,6};
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final int N = arr.length;
        int h = 1;
        while(h<(N/3))
            h = 3*h + 1;

        while(h>=1)
        {
            for(int i=h;i<N;i++)
            {
                for(int j=i;j>=h && (arr[j-h]>arr[j]);j-=h)
                {
                    int temp = arr[j-h];
                    arr[j-h] = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = temp;
                }
            }

            h=h/3;
        }

        for(int x:arr)
            System.out.println(x);
    }

}
```

Now the problem is, I cannot understand how the worst case complexity of Shell sort comes to  `O((nlog(n))^2)` . Please correct me if I did anything wrong.

Comment: its worst case is "n^1.5"

Comment: then, is 3√n (cube root of N) better worst case than , O((nlog(n))^2)

Comment: nps. Dont worry we dont charge you for asking question or helping you. We are there to help you :)

Comment: belongs on https://programmers.stackexchange.com/